# SQL Server: are backups between same major/minor version but different build compatible among them?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

For example a backup executed on SQL Server 10.50.6000.34 can always be restored on SQL Server `10.50.4000.0` or `10.50.2500.0`. All of them indicates an SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.xxxx.xx) but different build (service pack 2,3 etc).

From some tests that I did seems that there are no problems but I want to know if this is always possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should always be possible to restore within the same version, irrespective of service packs and other updates. Having said that, it is also recommend that you keep up with service releases so in an ideal world this won't be an issue.

One thing to note that throws some people off is that 2008 and 2008R2 are considered different versions (not one being a service release of the other) so you can't restore a backup from the latter with the former.

Comment: This is almost, but not *completely* true -- notably, SQL Server 2005 SP2 introduced vardecimal storage, giving a version (612) that cannot be restored on earlier versions of 2005 (which use 611). This is a rare situation, though, and I don't see MS repeating it any time soon. [List of internal database versions](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html).

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgotten that niggle. Though if you did explicitly enable `vardecimal` in 2005sp2, as it isn't available by default, you are hopefully aware of the implications. 2005 is out of its support lifetime (as of 2016-04-12) anyway, though soon (2019-07-09) 2008 and 2008r2 will be too.

Comment: A caution here you cannot restore backup *system* databases of higher version no (like 10.50.6000) on lower version like(10.50.4000).